# How to send multiple email with cc using Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, mailer

I need to send email to multiple users provided with cc using CI.
My code is as shown below:
This below code worked for sending email for single user but i need to send same message to multiple user at a same time..

```
                $this->load->library('email', $config);            

                $to = 'User email address here';
                $subject = 'Alert information On Products';
                $message = "Dear user,Our new product has been launched.Please visit our site for more informations";                 
                $this->load->library('email');
                // from address
                $this->email->from('admin_email_address');
                $this->email->to($to); // to Email address
                $this->email->cc('email_address_one'); 
                $this->email->subject($subject); // email Subject
                $this->email->message($message);
                $this->email->send();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try to use , seperated email in $this->email->cc function like this .

```
 $this->email->cc('email1@test.com,email2@test.com,email3@test.com');
```

you can also use like this

```
$this->email->to('one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com');
```

for email reference follow the link [Here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html)

Answer (score 1):

try to use an array, to send email to multiple users...

```
$list = array('one@example.com', 'two@example.com', 'three@example.com');
$this->email->to($list);
$this->email->subject('This is my subject');
$this->email->message('This is my message');
$this->email->send();
```